# Function which returns a callback or a promise

Tags: javascript

I'm building a library and I want to make it so consumers can call my functions either with callbacks or promises.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you receive a callback use it. If you don't, then return a promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is completely dependent on the use case.

The answer to the "what's the best way" for anything in software is "it depends".

That being said, a typical approach would be to branch on the arguments passed. If a callback is given, use it, if not, return a promise.

Here's one idea (where underlying logic is in a promise-returning `doStuff` function:

```
function myModule(cb) {
  if (cb) {
    doStuff()
      .then(result => cb(null, result))
      .catch(err => cb(err));
  }
  return doStuff();
}
```

My 2 cents:

The only real benefit to supporting both of these approaches is if you need to support environments without promises.

Otherwise it's just extra complexity that isn't necessary.

Now you have to maintain twice the logic in your code.

Moreover, having a function that has an inconsistent return type or runs in inconsistent ways (promises use microtasks while other async mechanisms might use regular tasks), is not particularly beneficial.

Subtle inconsistency isn't a typically desired feature.

Comment: you can simply pass the callback to the catch. It is a function where the first argument is the error, thus passing it to catch directly will behave the same.

Comment: @RobertMennell sure, although that's not really relevant for the task at hand. There's many ways my example can be improved.

Comment: +1. At least for node, I'd just return promises and let the caller use `callbackify` if desired. https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_callbackify_original

Comment: Damn I didn't know `callbackify` was a thing! I love it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always return a promise, not going to break anything. Detect if the callback is defined, if it is, execute it.

```js
function doubleIt(x, callback) {
  return new Promise( (resolve) => {
    var ans = x * 2
    resolve(ans)
    callback && callback(ans)
  })
}

doubleIt(4).then(res => console.log(res))

doubleIt(10, res => console.log(res))
```